# C++ crashes when printing variable declared in header

Tags: c++, opengl, header, crash, runtime-error

I am making a `Camera` class in c++ that I use for OpenGL. When I try to print any variable that was declared in `Camera.h`, the program crashes. But it does not crash if I set or get the value of the variable What am I doing wrong?

### Camera.h

```
    #ifndef CAMERA_H
    #define CAMERA_H

    class Camera
    {
        public:
            Camera();
            Camera(float xP, float yP, float zP);
            void move(float x, float y, float z);

        protected:
        private:
            float xPos, yPos, zPos;
    };

    #endif // CAMERA_H
```

### Camera.cpp

```
    #include "Camera.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <GL/glut.h>

    using namespace std;

    Camera::Camera()
    {
    }

    Camera::Camera(float xP, float yP, float zP)
    : xPos(xP), yPos(yP), zPos(zP)
    {
    }

    void Camera::move(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
        //None of this crashes:
        xPos = 1;
        yPos = xPos;
        //Crashes here:
        cout << "mainCamera x = " << xPos << endl;
    }
```

The crash message I get is:

> opengl.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

---

## Edit

If I put the line `float xPos, yPos, zPos;` in the public section in `Camera.h`, and call

```
    Camera mainCamera(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cout << "mainCamera x = " << mainCamera.xPos << endl;
```

...in the `main.cpp`, it works just fine and prints:

> mainCamera x = 0

Comment: How does it crash? What error do you get? And where, in which line in the program? Can you show how you call the move function?

Comment: You should probably initialize the values of `xPos`, `yPos`, and `zPos` in the `Camera::Camera()` constructor. Probably to `0`. C++ does not guarantee that numerical variables start at `0`. That shouldn't cause the crash, though.

Comment: Q: What platform are you on?  Windows?  Linux?  Something else?  Q: Are you running from a terminal session or command prompt? Can you even do terminal output ("cout/printf") in your program's environment?  Q: Do you have a debugger (MSVS or gdb)?

Comment: Are you possibly mixing debug and release in the same application? Remember on windows with Visual Studio it is not safe to use Debug dlls with Release executables or vice versa.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm on windows xp. Using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC compiler. Yes, I can cout. I'm not using a debuger, and don't know how to.

Comment: Since you are new to c++, my first recommendation is to learn how to work the debugger to step through code and examine variable values.

Comment: Does a cout without access to the variables work? If not, move the cout out to the caller of that code, and then to the caller of that, until it does work. Might be some issue related to threading, i.e. main thread can write but OpenGL thread can not. Do you have more than one thread?

Comment: @MvG, Yes, cout works without variables, it will even work with a local variable declared in the function. I'm not using multi-threading.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the OpenGL initialisation, and as a result `glTranslatef` is writing the resulting matrix somewhere it shouldn't, causing memory corruption. This needn't affect the `Camera` instance directly - e.g. the `cout` implementation or the heap could have been corrupted. If that's true, we need to see the initialisation code, and we also need an OpenGL expert (which I'm not).

Comment: @Steve314 Oh wow. Right on. I removed the `glTranslatef` line and it works just fine.

Comment: How are you supposed to use OpenGL in multiple classes? I suspect that's what I did wrong. I used `#include <GL/glut.h>` in `Camera.cpp`.

Comment: @Dan - as far as I know, it shouldn't matter where you call GL functions from within your application, so long as you call them in the correct order. GL maintains some state in the background. If you haven't done the correct initialisation, that background state may be in a bad state. Ideally that shouldn't be possible, but sometimes for a library to detect every possible error condition is too inefficient and programmers are expected to know how to avoid those conditions - which is a bit harsh on beginners, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. And this one was a dumb one. I forgot to include `windows.h` in `Main.cpp`, which for some reason weird reason it stopped floats from being printed out (???). It works perfectly now.

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: That's not the problem.  My guess is that you have a subtle error(s) somewhere else in your code that's causing a memory corruption.  While changing the code might delay the problem's(s') manifestation, it's not a fix.

Comment: I've printed plenty of floats from programs in C++ that don't `#include <windows.h>`. It's possible that something included has resulted in the programs memory layout being changed, so that memory corruption is still happening but in a non-fatal way - but symptoms may recur later when other changes modify the memory layout again. I won't completely discount the chance that including that has genuinely fixed the problem, but it'd be more than a little strange.

Comment: [According to this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Initialization) - "Because OpenGL is platform-independent, there is not a standard way to initialize OpenGL; each platform handles it differently." and "If you are using the C/C++ language binding for OpenGL, then you are strongly advised to use a window toolkit for managing this task.". I've played a very small amount with OpenGL in C++ (literally one polygon) and I used [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). One minor hassle - you have to build wxWidgets with `USE_OPENGL=1`.

Comment: Actually, reading [this bit](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Getting_Functions), there's a certain amount of WTF in OpenGL. "For most libraries you are familiar with, you simply #include a header file, make sure a library is linked into your project or makefile, and it all works. **OpenGL doesn't work that way.**" (my emphasis).